# Haskell Snap: Session example

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I've been googling around for an example on how to use Snap session. Nothing so far.
Can someon please point me to an article or something with a simple example of a cookie based session?

A code snippet would be very appriciated.
Something like putting a username in the session and checking for its existence and validity before every request. I looked at Snap.extension.session but I am still too noob to figure out how to use it just from the library code.

I understand that setInSession is the function to put the session value in the cookie but I cant quite figure out how to use it from the signature:

```
setInSession k v = Map.insert k v `liftM` getSession >>= setSession
```

or how to glu the whole thing together.

I dont know if it is against the rules to ask for a bit of example code but I would not do it if I could find anything on the net.

Thank you in advance.

**--- UPDATE ---**

I followed the example below and the links but things are still not comming out right.

I just want a simple test that reads a key and a value and puts it in session cookie then I want to read the session value back and display.

So I initialized my session and put it in the main application state.

```
s <- nestSnaplet "" sess $ initCookieSessionManager "config/site_key.txt" "sess" (Just 3600)
```

The first confusion is the key that session initialization fanction needs.
The key is not created during the initial project setup.

So how do I create it?
Where is the key supposed to go in the project file structure so the function can find it?

Then the handlers:

```
putCookie :: Handler App App ()
putCookie = do
  par <- getPostParams
  let k = T.decodeUtf8 $ head (par ! (B.pack "key"))
  let v = T.decodeUtf8 $ head (par ! (B.pack "value"))
  with sess $ setInSession k v
  heistLocal (bindString "message" "Cookie inserted!") $ render "reply"
```

This one just reads the key and the value from a web form and it is supposed to put the key value pair in the cookie. Well, apparently it does not.

```
shCookie :: Handler App App ()
shCookie = do
  v <- with sess $ getFromSession "key"
  heistLocal (bindString "message" (fromMaybe "" v)) $ render "reply"
```

This one just reads it back and displays. I always get an empty string which means there is no such thing.

Does any of the above look incorrect? Where do I make a mistake?
It all compiles correct but the session cookie is just not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `Snap.extension.session` means [this](https://github.com/snapframework/snap-auth/blob/master/src/Snap/Extension/Session.hs) module? AFAIK the `snap-auth` package is deprecated.

You can use new [session api](https://github.com/snapframework/snap/blob/master/src/Snap/Snaplet/Session.hs) implemented as [snaplet](http://snapframework.com/docs/tutorials/snaplets-tutorial).

Check out an [example](http://blog.dbpatterson.com/post/20132704797) how to setup your application to use session and auth snaplets. Then you will be able to store data in session:

```
data App = App
{ _heist :: Snaplet (Heist App)
, _sess :: Snaplet SessionManager
, _auth :: Snaplet (AuthManager App)
}
makeLens ''App

myHandler :: Handler App App ()
myHandler = do
  with sess $ setInSession "key" "value"
```

ADDED:

File with site key will be created automatically. The function `initCookieSessionManager` (defined [here](https://github.com/snapframework/snap/blob/master/src/Snap/Snaplet/Session/Backends/CookieSession.hs)) uses `getKey` function from `clientsession` package (see [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/clientsession/0.7.4.2/doc/html/Web-ClientSession.html#v%3agetKey)). From the docs: `If the file does not exist or is corrupted a random key will be generated and stored in that file.`

I think your handler doesn't works cos you didn't commit session (see `commitSession` [here](https://github.com/snapframework/snap/blob/master/src/Snap/Snaplet/Session.hs)) You can commit it in every handler that updates session, or use `wrapHandlers` and/or `withSession` to do it automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the example. I followed your links but things still dont work for some reason. I will update my original question with few more confusion points.

Comment: Nice one. Now everything works. All I needed was to add commitSession as you suggested. Thank you. Great help.

Comment: The example link is broken. Is it just me or is finding sample code for Snap authentication almost impossible?

Comment: @phatmann Did you try to generate simple project via `snap init`? It contains an example of signup, login and logout

Comment: @Yuras, just looked at the snap init code, this is just what I was looking for. Thanks so much! It sure explains why no one has posted a sample project :-) I am going to dive in and switch my happstack-lite project over to snap right now!